# Gatsby + Source from Wordpress + Build Automation

Tags: wordpress, continuous-integration, gatsby

I've set up Gatsby with Wordpress, but now I'm trying to figure out how the workflow of adding new content to the site via WP and having it show up as static markup on the server would work. Is there's a recommended way to automate the process building new WP content?

I'm guessing something like this would happen but not sure what hooks or tools already exist.

1. Publish a new piece of content via Wordpress on the server.
2. A Gatsby build kicks off. This would pull in [all] WP content and rebuild the [entire] website.
3. Push [move] the built static files to the web root on server

I'm also not clear on if Gatsby monitors the WP API for changes in real time or does it only do one request initially on startup?

Answer (score 1):

Gatsby does not monitor WordPress. You need to set up a webhook on the WordPress side to notify your build process whenever content has changed.

Comment: thanks yea I eventually figured out this is a limitation that was slowing down the dev cycle, so just using markdown now.

Comment: If you're building on Netlify you can setup webhooks to do that, depends if you want to keep all the admin stuff from WordPress. Otherwise a headless CMS might work, like contentful or the open source equivalent.